# Load a (0/1) string into a bit array

Tags: c#, string, bitarray

What is the smartest way to load a string like "10101011101010" directly into a new **bit array**? (**not a byte array**)

(The bits should remain in the same order as in the list.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with LINQ:

```
var res = new BitArray(str.Select(c => c == '1').ToArray());
```

Comment: This one so far works best (Soner came up with same idea). I am accepting this, but let me know about any new idea. Thank you dasblinkenlight.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `LINQ` on this case like;

```
var yourbitarray = new BitArray(yourstring.Select(s => s == '1').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
string bits = "101010101010";
byte[] bytes = bits.ToCharArray().Select(c => (byte)c == '0' ? 0 : 1).ToArray();
```

Might work...

or

```
byte[] bytes = bits.Select(c => (byte)c == '0' ? 0 : 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry. See one of the other excellent answers in that case (or pass the byte array into the constructor of the BitArray class).